# PDOException (2006) SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

MySQL server has gone away , i was working in laravel ,when i go to admin page this error is coming,please help me on this.

when i am Adding this line into my.cnf file as "max_allowed_packet=64M " after that when starting the mysql, it is showing the "[ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file /etc/mysql/my.cnf at line 27!".

Comment: when i am Adding this line into my.cnf file "max_allowed_packet=64M "
after that when starting the mysql it is showing the "[ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file /etc/mysql/my.cnf at line 27!"

Comment: Your line added needs to be after [mysqld] in your cnf (and there can only be one section/group with this name.